# Rotating car using multiple images

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to take an animation via css or jquery using multiple images.
I get this ideea when i see an windows skin.
Is this possible?
Is about a car that is rotating.
Some advices please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've actually do this before with just some simple JavaScript.  I made it like a "slideshow" every click would cycle to another image that would rotate left or right.  Say from front to back you have 10 images, if you keep going "right" you will just back to 1 and so on to create a rotate.

Comment: any demo to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Read about [CSS Sprite Sheet Animations with steps()](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/css-sprite-sheet-animations-steps) at Treehouse.

Comment: I think will be ok this solution.The fact is that i have multiple images that makes a car rotating so i guess will be more difficult.